# WordPress-How to give css inline style to a shortcode?

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

Is there any way or is it possible to give a inline css style in shortcode tag, e.g Consider the following shortcodes: 
 `[vc_row]some content[/vc_row]` 
 in above beginning shortcode tag i.e`[vc_row]` , can we give inline css style in it like `[vc_row style="background-color:red;"]`  or some other way to give it inline css style. I just curious some way to do it..

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can pass a `css` parameter.

This parameter takes a CSS block with a unique class:

```
[vc_row css=".vc_custom_1446466804838{background-color: red;}"]
```

Sidenote: You are not *'giving CSS to a shortcode'*. The shortcode you are using outputs HTML markup and the nature of the shortcode just so happens to allow a parameter with CSS to be applied to the row that is created.

Comment: Yes, You are right, the visual composer also added this same inline style css like yours when we set color from row design setting tab. Maybe I have some other issue...